# Why can't I read this array?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I am currently working on a plugin for WordPress, and i am trying to fetch the widget options using `get_options`. As a result, I get an array with the options and option name as the key, but for some reason I can't read it:

```
$options = get_option('widget_widgetname');
var_dump($options);
```

This is the output of `var_dump()`:

```
array(2) { [2]=> array(5) 
           { 
             ["string"]=> string(6) "Search" 
             ["title"]=> string(12) "WDSearchForm" 
             ["show_wrapper"]=> string(0) "" 
             ["animate"]=> string(0) "" 
             ["animateWidth"]=> string(2) "80" 
           } 
           ["_multiwidget"]=> int(1) }
```

but when I do the following, it doesn't work:

```
echo $options["string"]; // No output
echo $options["title"]; // No output
```

Comment: it seems that you need to access it like this: $options[2]["string"]

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in your `var_dump`, you have a multi-dimensional array.

You should use:

```
echo $options[2]["string"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is a nested array. Try:

```
echo $options[2]["string"];
echo $options[2]["title"];
```

Here's a reformatted dump that makes the structure a bit clearer:

```
array(2) {
    [2]=> array(5) { 
             ["string"]=> string(6) "Search" 
             ["title"]=> string(12) "WDSearchForm" 
             ["show_wrapper"]=> string(0) "" 
             ["animate"]=> string(0) "" 
             ["animateWidth"]=> string(2) "80" 
           }
    ["_multiwidget"]=> int(1)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a multidimentional array. Try `echo $options[2]["string"]`

Answer (score 1):

It is a two-dimensional array. This should do the trick:

```
echo $options[2]["string"];
echo $options[2]["title"];
```

or

```
$options = $options[2];

echo $options["string"];
echo $options["title"];
```

Comment: Can't believe it was so simple... any idea why WordPress does that? is it always going to be under "2"?

Comment: @WebDeskIL I got no clue about WordPress internals, sorry.

Comment: That's ok, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $options[2]["string"]; // output
echo $options[2]["title"]; // output
```